# Binding a class to a WPF Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have an object, which holds an observable collection
Im trying to wrap my head around how to stick this all into a treeview.
So the main object would be a parent and items in observable collection are sub-children.
Currently the class has public string property which could be bound to a header. 
Here are parts of the class:

```
public class ServerObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _serverName;
    ObservableCollection<string> _instanceList;

    public ObservableCollection<string> InstanceList
    {
        get { return _instanceList; }
    }

    public string ServerName
    {
        get { return _serverName; }
        set
        {
            _serverName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ServerName");
        }
    }

    public ServerObject(string name, string version)
    {

        ServerName = name;
        _instanceList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is with HierarchicalDataTemplates.  Define two or more templates.  In the template declaration line add a type indicator for your object.  Also, add an ItemsSource attribute which points to the next level down.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate Datatype="{x:Type local:mySerberObject}" ItemsSource="{Binding InstanceList}"/>
```

Bind the top level collection to the treeview, and you should be off and running.  Style the datatemplates to suit your taste.

If you are currently using MVVM (or if you plan to start using it) check out the link below for a really good article about [**using the treeview with MVVM**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx).

Comment: Didn't realise I had to bind to top level, this explains what I was doing wrong. I was binding to the serves list. Thanks

Comment: <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:ServerObject}" ItemsSource="{Binding InstanceList}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ServerName}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
Kinda works, I get the servers listed and they expand, however items inside appear to be missing text. Im missing some obvious step am I?

Comment: I have found it easiest to use VMs containing both the item at hand and child items when working with treeviews.  For instance,  I have a ShipmentsViewModel which contains my collection of ShipmentViewModels.  Each ShipmentViewModel contains a Shipment, a collection of PackageViewModels, and a collection of NoteViewModels.  I bind only the ShipmentsViewModel (I actually generally use a CollectionViewSource to control filtering and whatnot) to the TreeView, and define my templates in the hierarchy that I want using only a bound string value.  Then I style.

Comment: Are you getting any databinding errors in your output window?  If so, you may have a binding reference that is not getting qualified correctly.  If you have access to Mole (http://www.molosoft.com/  Highly recommended) you can trace those bindings and figure out what is going on a little easier.